# SFINAE make unique

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, unique-ptr

Is there a way to check whether type `T` is constructible with variadic template arguments pack `Args...`? I don't care whether the solution will be efficient or not I just want to SFINAE or `static_assert` in debug mode.

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

For everyone else interested, this solution worked for me in C++ 11

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
auto make_unique(Args&&... args) -> decltype(std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)))
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

Comment: trailing return type? `auto make_unique(Args&&... args) -> decltype(std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)))`?

Comment: If `T` can not be constructed with the arguments passed, then the `new T(...)` should fail and give a compiler error. Can you please elaborate on the problem you have that lead you to ask this question? Perhaps you should ask about that instead?

Comment: What you trying to do? Normally I see people wanting such template stuff because they want it to full through to a more generic template (e.g. do this if its random access iterator, do that if its bidirectional, fail otherwise). With just one template its going to fail on the `new` anyway?

Comment: It will fail I would just like it to be sfinae and give me an indication that I'm not providing the right arguments while I'm typing them. It's just a convenience thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a cheap way of checking if `T(Args...)` is a valid expression in a SFINAE-friendly manner, consider using *expression SFINAE* through a *trailing return type*:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto foo(Args&&... args) 
    -> decltype(T(std::forward<Args>(args)...), void())
{

}
```

`foo` will be "SFINAEd-out" if `T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` is not a valid expression.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in c++ 11 (no auto return)

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe this is c++11 :)

Comment: template<typename T, typename... Args>
 auto make_unique(Args&&... args) -> decltype(std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)), void())
 {
  return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
 } returns void for me on C++ 11

Comment: template<typename T, typename... Args>
 auto make_unique(Args&&... args) -> decltype(T(std::forward<Args>(args)...), void())
 {
  return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
 } also deduces to void

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe: well sure, because `, void()` is there :)

Comment: Oh now I get it the second argument is what we get for a non false type... awesome thank you. Any idea why the std implementation is not SFINAE? Is it for compile time reasons?